# Subtle point in definition of BNS invariant

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group.  Let $S(G)$ be the quotient of $\text{Hom}(G,\mathbb{R}) \setminus \{0\}$ by the equivalence relation that identifies two homomorphisms if they differ by scaling by a positive constant.  For a nonzero $\phi \in \text{Hom}(G,\mathbb{R})$, write $[\phi] \in S(G)$ for the associated equivalence class.

The Bieri-Neumann-Strebel (BNS) invariant of $G$ is a certain subset of $S(G)$.  The definition in the original paper is hard to parse, but in several places I have seen the following definition of it:

Fix a generating set $S$ of $G$.  Let $\text{Cay}(G,S)$ be the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to $S$.  Consider a nonzero $\phi \in \text{Hom}(G,\mathbb{R})$.  Define $X_{\phi} = \{\text{$g \in G$ $|$ $\phi(g) \geq 0$}\}$.  Then $[\phi] \in S(G)$ is in the BNS invariant if and only if the full subgraph of $\text{Cay}(G,S)$ spanned by $X_{\phi}$ is connected.

I have seen it asserted without proof or reference that the above property does not depend on the choice of generating set $S$.

**Question 1**: Can someone give me either a proof or reference for this?

**Question 2**: Can someone explain how to relate this to the definition in the original paper defining the BNS invariant?  A reference here would also be fine.

Comment: Hey Andy. Suppose that $S$ and $T$ are generating sets. If two elements $g_1,g_2\in G$ differ by an element of $T$, then they can be connected by a path in the $S$-Cayley graph on which $\phi$ does not get much smaller than the minimum of $\phi(g_1)$ and $\phi(g_2)$. This means that, if $X_\phi$ is connected in the $T$-Cayley graph, then for $n$ sufficiently large, any two points of $\{g|\phi(g)>n\}$ are connected by a path in the $S$-Cayley graph on which $\phi$ stays non-negative. Any $g\in X_\phi$ can reach $\{g|\phi(g)>n\}$ in the $S$-Cayley graph since some $s\in S$ satisfies $\phi(s)>0$.

Comment: @DavidCohen: Thanks!  A little embarrassed that I didn't see that (but it clears up an annoying technical point in a paper I am writing right now).

Comment: @AndyPutman, in case you are still interested in Q2, the original definition is essentially that the submonoid $X_\phi$ is left $FP_1.$. For a monoid this is equivalent to having a connected Cayley graph for some finite subset (not necessarily generators).

Comment: If your subgroup is connected then you get the Cayley graph of $X_\phi$ with respect to the generators of the group on which $\phi$ is positive is connected to the monoid is FP1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $S$ and $T$ be generating sets for $G$, and suppose that $X_\phi$ is $T$-connected (i.e., spans a connected subgraph in the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to $T$.) Let $[X_\phi]_S$ be the subgraph of $\text{Cay}(G,S)$ spanned by $X_\phi$. We must show that $[X_\phi]_S$ is connected.

Claim 1: For any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the set $\{g\in G:\phi(g)\geq n\}$ is $T$-connected.

Proof: This follows, by translation, from the fact that $X_\phi$ is $T$-connected.

Claim 2: There exists some $n$ such that for any $g\in G$ and $t\in T$, there is a path in $\text{Cay}(G,S)$ from $g$ to $gt$ such that if $v$ is a vertex of this path, then $\phi(v)>\phi(g)-n$ and $\phi(v)>\phi(gt)-n$.

Proof: For each $t\in T$, choose some word $w_t$ in the alphabet $S$ representing $t$. Choose $n$ so that it is larger than $|\phi(w)|$ whenever $w$ is a prefix or suffix of any $w_t$. The claim follows by connecting $g$ and $gt$ via the path given by $g \cdot w_t$.

If $n$ is as in Claim 2, it follows that any two points of $\{g\in G:\phi(g)\geq n\}$ may be connected by a path in $[X_\phi]_S$.

Claim 3: there is some $s \in S \cup S^{-1}$ such that $\phi(s) > 0$.

Proof: this follows from the fact that $\phi$ is not identically $0$, by definition.

By Claim 3 we see that, for any $g \in X_\phi$, there is a path $g,gs,gs^2,\ldots$ in $[X_\phi]_S$ from $g$ to $\{g\in G:\phi(g)\geq n\}$. Since any two vertices of $\{g\in G:\phi(g)\geq n\}$ may be connected by a path in $[X_\phi]_S$, it follows that $[X_\phi]_S$ is connected.

Answer (score 2):

This is a reference of question 2.

Various definitions (including the original one and the one you have given) of BNS invariant are discussed in Chapter C of [this lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0214.pdf) by Ralph Strebel who call the BNS invariant as "Sigma invariants".